# Without using subprocesses, is there a way to store multiple, separate plots from matplotlib in memory at once?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Normally one would type

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 x = np.random.randint(1, 100, 500)
 plt.hist(x)
 plt.savefig(mypath) # or plt.show()
```

However, say I want to create multiple plots, and I do not want to save any of them until all the plots have been created.  I tried doing the following

```
import importlib
plots = [importlib.import_module('matplotlib.pyplot') for _ in range(5)]
for plot in plots:
    plot.hist(np.random.randint(1,100, 500))
```

But when I run

```
plots[0].savefig(mypath) # or plots[0].show()
```

I get something like this:

[image]

It is obvious that it doesn't matter how I import `matplotlib.pyplot`, as it will always behave that way.

If I don't want to modify any images after reading them, I could do the following:

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig_files = [io.BytesIO() for _ in range(5)]

for f in fig_files:
    plt.hist(np.random.randint(1, 100, 500))
    plt.savefig(f) # save to BytesIO object
    plt.gcf().clear() # clear out plot so subsequent ones don't overlap like above image
    f.seek(0) # move to beginning of buffer so it can be read

for i, f in enumerate(fig_files):
    with open('test_img_%d.png' % i, 'wb') as out:
        out.write(f.read())
```

This will allow me to store the plots in memory until I am done with them. This is good if I want to avoid unnecessary disk writes, but still want to compress/simplify data along the way. However, if I want to modify different aspects of the plot (e.g., I want to adjust the scales after viewing all of the data/my title/subtitle will change depending on the overall results, etc.).

Is there any way to store the state of a plot in memory such that it can be modified later, and *then* written to disk/displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as with other things you want to store in memory you would assign your plots to variables.

Best also directly use the object-oriented approach of manipulating objects.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
x1 = np.random.randint(1, 100, 500)
ax1.hist(x1)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
x2 = np.random.randint(1, 100, 500)
ax2.hist(x2)

fig1.savefig("mypath.png")
fig2.savefig("myotherpath.png")
```

You may also store the figures in a list, like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

figures = []
for i in range(3):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    x = np.random.randint(1, 100, 500)
    ax.hist(x)
    figures.append(fig)

for i,fig in enumerate(figures):
    fig.savefig("mypath{}.png".format(i))
```